# Issue in displaying in SwiftUI while spliting a sentence into word array and display it in Text View

Tags: swiftui

I am new to SwiftUi, and I was trying to split a sentence (string) into list of words and displaying it in a Text view, and also apply format and tap gesture event for each words.

When I use ForEach loop in an HStack,

1. For smaller sentence formatting and tap gestures works fine.
2. For longer strings the words are distorted.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var sentence: String = "Thank you so much"

    var body: some View {
        
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            var wordList = sentence.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces)
            HStack {
                            ForEach(Array(wordList.enumerated()), id: \.element) { index, element in                
                                    Text(element)
                                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                        .font(.system(size: 16))
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                                print("\(index): \(element)")
                                            }
                                }
                        }
                    }

        } 
        }
}
```

[Small Sentence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hP8iY.jpg)

[Long Sentence 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN1vo.jpg)

[Long Sentence 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fezC.jpg)

I tried to use the reduce function, I am getting error "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions" when I have tap gesture in Text View

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var sentence: String = "Thank you so much" 

    
    var body: some View {
        
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            var wordList = sentence.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces)
            
            wordList.enumerated().reduce(Text(""))
                        { acc, pair in
                            acc
                            + Text(pair.1 + " ")
                                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    // cannot have onTapGesture getting error but I need for each word
                        }
                    }

        }
        }
}
```

I cannot use Text View concatenation

1. Sentence (string) is dynamic and does not have fixed array size
2. tap gesture not possible for each Text

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var sentence: String = "Thank you so much" // String is dynamic

    var body: some View {
        
    ZStack {
        VStack {
                var wordList = sentence.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces)
            HStack {                                     
                                Text(wordList[0])
                                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    // cannot have onTapGesture getting error but I need for each word
                    + Text(wordList[1])
                                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    // cannot have onTapGesture getting error but I need for each word
                    + Text(wordList[2])
                                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    // cannot have onTapGesture getting error but I need for each word
                    + Text(wordList[3])
                                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    // cannot have onTapGesture getting error but I need for each word
                        }
                    } 

        }
        }
}
```

Comment: This is what Attributed String is for you can only concatenate Text not View